# i want to store the input from an html form to an JSON file in the webpage itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

right now the value is being stored in an array on the server but i want to store it on the client side only in the webpage itself.i need to write the form data generated by the html form into a a json file and it should stay on page itself not sent to server. it is as if i am assiging name and value to a object.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<style>
body {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
font-size: 62.5%;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('path') .dblclick(function(){
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="80" height="32">
<path d="M10 15 l15 0 l2.5 -5 l5 10 l5 -10 l5 10 l5 -10 l5 10 l2.5 -5 l15 0"       stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">
<form action="array.php" method="post">
Component-ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
Componentval: <input type="text" name="var"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$("#form").serialize()` http://jsfiddle.net/D45LV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<form onsubmit="processForm();">
<script>
var object = {};
function processForm()
{
    object = {
        id: document.getElementById("id").value,
        var: document.getElementById("var").value
    };
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Though i would do some value validation check to make sure your element exist etc...